# Command button to show a user form

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to have an ActiveX command button show a user form named "DataEntryUserForm".

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

DataEntryUserForm.Show

End Sub
```

Above is the current code for the command button. When I click the button I receive the following error:

> Run-time error '424'
>   Object required

I tried looking around for a similar problem, but could not find anything.

Adding user form code:

```
Private Sub DataEntryUserForm_Initialize()

'Empty PatientIdentifierTextBox
PatientIdentifierTextBox.Value = ""

'Empty AgeTextBox
AgeTextBox.Value = ""

'Empty SexComboBox
SexComboBox.Clear

'Fill SexComboBox
With SexComboBox
.AddItem "Male"
.AddItem "Female"
End With

'Unselect AlergiesOptionButtons
AllergiesYesOptionButton1.Value = False
AllergiesNoOptionButton2.Value = False

'Set no car as default
CarOptionButton2.Value = True

'Empty PrimaryDiagnosisTextBox
PrimaryDiagnosisTextBox.Value = ""

'Empty ReasonforTransfusionTextBox
ReasonforTransfusionTextBox.Value = ""

'Empty NumberofTransfusionsTextBox
NumberofTransfusionsTextBox.Value = ""

'Empty TypeofTRXNComboBox
TypeofTRXNComboBox.Clear

'Fill TypeofTRXNComboBox
With TypeofTRXNComboBox
.AddItem "TACO"
.AddItem "TRALI"
.AddItem "TAD"
.AddItem "Allergic Reaction"
.AddItem "Hypotensive TRXN"
.AddItem "FNHTR"
.AddItem "AHTR"
.AddItem "DHTR"
.AddItem "DSTR"
.AddItem "TAGVHD"
.AddItem "TTI"
.AddItem "Other"
End With

'Empty TreatmentofTRXNTextBox
TreatmentofTRXNTextBox.Value = ""

'Empty NumberofTransfusionsBeforeTextBox
NumberofTransfusionsBeforeTextBox.Value = ""

'Empty SignsSymptomsTextBox
SignsSymptomsTextBox.Value = ""

'Empty ImputabilityComboBox1
ImputabilityComboBox1.Clear

'Fill ImputabilityComboBox1
With ImputabilityComboBox1
.AddItem "Definite"
.AddItem "Probable"
.AddItem "Possible"
.AddItem "Doubtful"
.AddItem "Ruled Out"
.AddItem "Not Determined"
End With

'Empty SeverityComboBox2
SeverityComboBox2.Clear

'Fill SeverityComboBox2
With SeverityComboBox2
.AddItem "Non-Severe"
.AddItem "Severe"
.AddItem "Life-threatening"
.AddItem "Death"
End With

'Unselect TreatmentOptionButtons
TreatmentDrugOptionButton1.Value = False
TreatmentProductsOptionButton2.Value = False
TreatmentDrugandProductOptionButton3.Value = False

'Empty TypeofDrugTextBox
TypeofDrugTextBox.Value = ""

'Clear ProductModCheckBox
VolumeReductionCheckBox1.Value = False
SalineWashingCheckBox2.Value = False

'Empty TRXNBeforeChangeTextBox
TRXNBeforeChangeTextBox.Value = ""

'Empty TRXNAfterChangeTextBox
TRXNAfterChangeTextBox.Value = ""

'Set Focus on NameTextBox
NameTextBox.SetFocus

End Sub
Private Sub OKButton_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Sheet1 active
Sheet1.Activate

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer information
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = PatientIdentifierTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = AgeTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = SexComboBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = PrimaryDiagnosisTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = ReasonforTransfusionTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = NumberofTransfusionsTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = TypeofTRXNComboBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = TreatmentofTRXNTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 10).Value = NumberofTransfusionsBeforeTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 11).Value = SignsSymptomsTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 12).Value = ImputabilityComboBox1.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 13).Value = SeverityComboBox2.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 15).Value = TypeofDrugTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 17).Value = TRXNBeforeChangeTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 18).Value = TRXNAfterChangeTextBox.Value


If AllergiesYesOptionButton1.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = 
AllergiesYesOptionButton1.Caption

If AllergiesNoOptionButton2.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = 
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value & " " & AllergiesNoOptionButton2.Caption

End If

If TreatmentDrugOptionButton1.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 14).Value = 
TreatmentDrugOptionButton1.Caption

If TreatmentProductsOptionButton2.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 
14).Value = Cells(emptyRow, 14).Value & " " & 
TreatmentProductsOptionButton2.Caption

If TreatmentDrugandProductOptionButton3.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 14).Value = Cells(emptyRow, 14).Value & " " & 
TreatmentDrugandProductOptionButton3.Caption

End If

If VolumeReductionCheckBox1.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 16).Value = VolumeReductionCheckBox1.Caption

If SalineWashingCheckBox2.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 16).Value = Cells(emptyRow, 16).Value & " " & SalineWashingCheckBox2.Caption

End If

End Sub
Private Sub ClearButton_Click()

Call UserForm_Initialize

End Sub
Private Sub CancelButton_Click()

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your 
`Private Sub UserForm_Initialize ()` code to

`Private Sub DataEntryUserForm_Initialize ()`

(Double Click into your UserForm to view/edit it's codes.)

(And I'm not sure whether did you add your userform or not. If not try adding UserForm - In the Visual Basic Editor click the Insert UserForm button - or go to Insert > UserForm)

Comment: Added user form coding

Comment: So what's the result? If it still doesn't work, try open your Visual basic window and press F8 one by one, and tell me which line gives an error/becomes highlighted.